# MissingMethodException while using shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Cloudbees 2.121.3.1

Partial Jenkinsfile of the main component that is failing viz. Alfaclient:

```
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: "", description: "List of components", name: 'componentsToUpdate'),
                        string(defaultValue: "refs%2Fheads%2Fproject%2Fintegration", description: "BuildInfo CommitID", name: 'commitId'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Tag to release, e.g. 1.1.0-integration", name: 'releaseTag'),
                        string(defaultValue: "", description: "Forked buildInfo repo. Be aware right commit ID!!!", name: 'fork')]),
                        [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '7', numToKeepStr: '5']],
                        disableConcurrentBuilds()])

@Library(['jenkins-shared-utilities@integration/CICD-344-refactor-bitbucket-notify-handler','jenkins-shared-stages@integration/CICD-344-refactor-bitbucket-notify-handler','jenkins-shared-pipelines@integration/CICD-344-refactor-bitbucket-notify-handler']) _
.
.
.
returnValue = componentPipeline {
        componentsToUpdate = rewriteDependencies
        commitId = buildInfoCommitId
        runOnForkedRepo = forkedRepo
    }
```

The componentPipeline in the above code is a scripted pipeline located in vars of **jenkins-shared-pipelines**
The partial Jenkinsfile(which doesn't do much!) of jenkins-shared-pipelines

```
#!groovy

@Library(['jenkins-shared-utilities@integration/CICD-344-refactor-bitbucket-notify-handler','jenkins-shared-stages@integration/CICD-344-refactor-bitbucket-notify-handler']) _
```

Partial code for componentPipeline:

```
def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    def componentName = null
    body.delegate = config
    body()
    def rewriteDependency = config.componentsToUpdate
    def buildInfoCommitId = config.commitId
    def forkedBuildInfo = config.runOnForkedRepo

    def PIPELINE_NAME = "Component Pipeline"
    .
    .
    .
    setupSharedUtils(callingScript: this)
    .
    .
    .
    def build_status = "ok"
            stage(CLEAN_STAGE) {
            .
            .
            .
            bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildStart("Build ${env.BUILD_ID} started at ${env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP}", PIPELINE_NAME)

            }
            stage(GET_BUILD_INFO) {
            .
            .
            .
            build_status = "${COMPILE_STAGE} failed in build ${env.BUILD_ID} with exit code ${exit_code}"
            bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildFail(build_status, PIPELINE_NAME)

            }   

}
```

Now comes the main library viz. **jenkins-shared-utilities**. It has the following structure:
vars
   containing scripts that would act as global variables for components like **Alfaclient**.

bitbucketUtilities.groovy

```
import groovy.transform.Field
import com.jenkins.utilities.bitbucket.*
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

@Field final String STEP_NAME = getClass().getName()
@Field final BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler bitbucketUtilities = new BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler(this,env)

@NonCPS
def notifyBuildStart(String message, String displayName) {

    //Remove
    println "bitbucketUtilities global vars, env: "+env
    validateCall(this, message, displayName)

    bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildStart(message, displayName)
}

@NonCPS
def notifyBuildSuccess(String message, String displayName) {

    //Remove
    println "bitbucketUtilities global vars, env: "+env

     validateCall(this, message, displayName)

    bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildSuccess(message, displayName)
}

@NonCPS
def notifyBuildFail(String message, String displayName) {

    //Remove
    println "bitbucketUtilities global vars, env: "+env

    validateCall(this, message, displayName)

    bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildFail(message, displayName)
}

@NonCPS
private void validateCall(def script, String message, String displayName) {

    if(message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
        script.error("[ERROR][${script.STEP_NAME}] Build message not provided")
    }

    if(displayName == null || displayName.isEmpty()){
        script.error("[ERROR][${script.STEP_NAME}] displayName not provided!")
    }

}
```

setupSharedUtils.groovy

```
import groovy.transform.Field
import com.jenkins.utilities.ServiceLocator

void call(Map parameters = [:]) {
    if (parameters?.callingScript == null) {
        step.error(
            "[ERROR][setupSharedUtils] No reference to surrounding script " +
            "provided with key 'callingScript', e.g. 'callingScript: this'.")
    } else {
        parameters.callingScript.serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.getInstance()
    }
}
```

src
   packages containing classes like BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler

```
class BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler implements  Serializable {

    private def script
    private def env
    //TODO: Think if this should be an enum but iterating it will be an overhead
    private static final String [] bitbucketBuildStatuses = ["INPROGRESS", "SUCCESSFUL", "FAILED"]

    BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler(def script, def env) {
        //Remove
        script.println "In constructor of BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler, env: {$env}, script: {$script}"
        this.script = script
        this.env = env
    }

    def notifyBuildStart(String message, String displayName) {
        script.println "${displayName} Notify commit: ${env.GIT_COMMIT} build start: ${message}"
        postBuildStatus(script,"INPROGRESS", displayName, env.BUILD_URL, env.GIT_COMMIT, message)
    }

    def notifyBuildSuccess(String message, String displayName) {
        script.println "${displayName} Notify commit: ${env.GIT_COMMIT} build success: ${message}"
        postBuildStatus(script,'SUCCESSFUL', displayName, env.BUILD_URL, env.GIT_COMMIT, message)
    }

    def notifyBuildFail(String message, String displayName) {
        script.println "${displayName} Notify commit: ${env.GIT_COMMIT} build fail: ${message}"
        postBuildStatus(script,'FAILED', displayName, env.BUILD_URL, env.GIT_COMMIT, message)
    }

.
.
.   
}
```

*****Error*****

While the library jenkins-shared-utilities seems to be available to Alfaclient, somehow, in the global vars bitbucketUtilities.groovy, the variable 'bitbucketUtilities' (@Field final BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler bitbucketUtilities) isn't identified. Note that the @NonCPS annotation is immaterial - the Exception persists with/without it, also, note the println in bitbucketUtilities global vars and in the constructor of Groovy class viz. BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler

```
In constructor of BitbucketBuildOperationsHandler, env: {org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@75f03f42}, script: {bitbucketUtilities@3e86aed8}
[Pipeline] echo
bitbucketUtilities global vars, env: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@75f03f42
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
bitbucketUtilities global vars, env: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl@75f03f42
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.notifyBuildFail() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [Exception No signature of method: java.lang.Class.notifyBuildStart() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [Build 44 started at 20190301-0810, Component Pipeline] in build 44, ...]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at bitbucketUtilities.notifyBuildFail(bitbucketUtilities.groovy:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at componentPipeline.call(file:/var/jenkins_home/jobs/TDE_component_Current_Release/jobs/AlfaClient/branches/integrati.g220hfrp5s3u.y-handler/builds/44/libs/jenkins-shared-pipelines/vars/componentPipeline.groovy:306)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor617.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```